# libjpeg installed and linked but not found when install other libraries

Tags: python, macos, installation, lib, libjpeg

I am using Mac OSX 10.14
The error message I got when installing HDF4 library (https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/support/HDF+4.2.14#files) is

```
ld: library not found for -ljpeg
```

I have tried:

```
brew update
brew install libjpeg 
brew unlink libjpeg
brew link libjpeg
```

also tried:

```
xcode-select --install
```

also tried:

```
git clone https://github.com/LuaDist/libjpeg.git
./configure make make instal...
```

All of the above are successful, but I still cannot get rid of the same error message when installing other libs that requires libjpeg (`ld: library not found for -ljpeg`).

Comment: What command did you run before getting that error message? Why have you installed Lua JPEG?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
I was trying to install HDF4 via https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/support/HDF+4.2.14#files 
The command I used is 
./configure
make

What is Lua JPEG?

Comment: You said you used `git` to clone and install Lua JPEG, didn't you? I can't imagine you need that and **homebrew** libjpeg. I would remove your git clone of LuaJPEG, remove **homebrew** libjpeg and then `brew install libjpeg`. Then run `brew doctor` and correct any issues.

Comment: You probably need to find where libjpeg is installed, and tell configure with `./configure --with-jpeg=/path_to_JPEG_install_directory`

Comment: Sometimes, the library is also installed only with a version suffix. Assuming you find it at `/usr/lib/libjpeg.so.1.2`, you should use this path in the command @Phillippe described or create a generic symlink `ln -sf /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.1.2 /usr/lib/libjpeg.so`, so this version will always be automatically recognized. The output of the `make install` should point you to where the files have been placed.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen no, but I managed to convert the HDF4 data to tif using other libraries. I was working on MISR L1B1 and L1B2 data.